# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined common.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api v3 and got this error while using the

**map.fitBounds(bounds);** function

Here is the error snapshot on console
[image]

And Here is the Code:

```
var arr = [{lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}, {lat: 12.97, lng: 77.59}];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i]));
}
map.fitBounds(bounds); //If I comment this line in m code, the error is gone but map does not load.
```

what is the problem? Also how can I solve it?

Comment: show your whole code

Comment: Please see the code now..

Comment: is your code in onload method?

Comment: No. It is called on click of a button

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  Where do you create the `map`?  Where do you create the `bounds`?

Comment: I had the exact error description, line and uglified method names. And it was because I declared in a script a `var self` that went into `window`. Maps API checks `window.self` and breaks.
Just rename that var.
And if that's your case too, it will prove the need to provide MCTR examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 10):

My guess is that somewhere in your code you have a `self = this` without a `var` declaration in front of it.

When you forget the `var` you are creating a global variable -- or in this case, redefining the global `self` as your local function.  This will cause a hiccup in the Google Maps code which expects `self` to be `Window` and lead to the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined(…)`

This kind of error is why some developers prefer to use `that` or some other term rather than `self` for scope control .  If you are a super careful coder and never forget your `var` declarations you'll be fine. But for those humans among us who occasionally mess up, using `that` can save hours of frustrating debugging.*

* *Those super careful coders would say that we deserve the hours of frustrating debugging because we are careless* :)

Comment: In my case the transpiler was doing that `self = this` for me (using ecma6). This answer really saved my day, thanks.

Comment: if you are confuse about who is that "self" just put a breackpoint in the error and type "self" in the chrome console.

Comment: Man! You just saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [google.maps.LatLngBounds.extend](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) method does not take [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral) objects as arguments (yet).

> extend(point:LatLng) | Return Value:  LatLngBounds
>
> Extends this bounds to contain the given point.

Translate them into [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) objects.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var arr = [{lat: -25.363,lng: 131.044}, {lat: 12.97,lng: 77.59}];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng));
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77pdtptd/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var arr = [{lat: -25.363,lng: 131.044}, {lat: 12.97,lng: 77.59}];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: arr[i],
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle. A perfect one but the solution is not working.

Comment: You have the same error?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue in your question.

Comment: Yes, I have the same error. The Fiddle you provided is the perfect code I am using. Can you suggest what else can be the issue?